# Conditions for $f(x_n,y_n) - f(x_0, y_n) \to 0$ if $(x_n,y_n) \to (x_0,y_0)$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, continuity, terminology, uniform-continuity

I have $x_n \to x_0$ and $y_n \to y_0$ as $n \to \infty$. Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued function.

> **Question**: Under which conditions do I have
>
> $$f(x_n, y_n) - f(x_0, y_n) \to 0 $$
>
> as $n \to \infty$?

I know two separate conditions, but I was wondering if there were other less restrictive assumptions for the convergence listed above.

> **Condition 1**: There is a neighborhood $\mathcal{B}$ of $y_0$ on which $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $x$ uniformly in $y$, i.e
>
> $$ \sup_{y \in \mathcal{B}} \left|f(x_n, y) - f(x_0, y)\right| \to 0 $$

in which case we have, for $n$ larger enough so that $y_n \in \mathcal{B}$,

$$|f(x_n, y_n) - f(x_0, y_n)| \le \sup_{y \in \mathcal{B}} \left|f(x_n, y) - f(x_0, y)\right| \to 0$$

Alternatively,

> **Condition 2**: $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$.

We then have, through the triangle inequality,

$$\begin{align}|f(x_n, y_n) - f(x_0, y_n)|
 &\le  |f(x_n, y_n) - f(x_0, y_0)| + |f(x_0, y_n) - f(x_0, y_0)| \to 0
 \end{align}$$

Neither condition implies the other. For example, the following condition satisfies Condition 1 but not Condition 2 for $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$,

> **Example 1**:
>   $$      f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{align}
>         1  ,   & \text{ for } y \in    \mathbb{Q}\\
>         -1 ,   & \text{ for } y \notin \mathbb{Q}
>         \end{align}\right.  $$

while this function satisfies Condition 2 but not Condition 1,

> **Example 2**:
>   $$      f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{align}
>          y,   & \text{ for }   x \in    \mathbb{Q} \\
>          - y,   & \text{ for } x \notin \mathbb{Q} 
>         \end{align}\right.  $$

Maybe I am missing a more fundamental condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not amazingly useful, but I've seen in the literature an assumption similar to the following:

> **Condition 3**: For any sequence of balls $\{ B(y_0, \delta_n )\}$ centered at $x_0 $ of radius $\delta_n \to 0$, we have 
>   $$ \sup_{y \in B(y_0,\delta_n)} \left|f(x_n, y) - f(x_0, y)\right| \to 0 $$

That Condition 3 is sufficient can be seenby taking $\{ \delta_n \}$ such that $\delta_n > |y_n - y_0|$ for every $n$.

Clearly Condition 1 implies Condition 3.

Condition 2 also implies Condition 3.

**Proof.**

First, note that, from the triangle inequality,

$$\begin{align}\sup_{y \in B(y_0,\delta_n)} \left|f(x_n, y) - f(x_0, y)\right| 
&\le \sup_{y \in B(y_0,\delta_n)} \left|f(x_n, y) - f(x_0, y_0)\right| \\
&+\sup_{y \in B(y_0,\delta_n)} \left|f(x_0, y) - f(x_0, y_0)\right|
 \end{align}$$

From continuity at $(x_0,y_0)$ both terms can be made arbitrarily small by picking a $n$ large enough.

We can then apply Condition 3 to Example 2.

> **Example 2** continued: We have
>
> $$ \sup_{y \in B(y_0,\delta_n)} \left|f(x_n, y) - f(x_0, y)\right| =  \left\{\begin{align}
>          0,   & \text{   if both $x_n$ and $x_0$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$, or both not in $\mathbb{Q}$ }    \\
>          2\delta_n   & \text{   otherwise } 
>         \end{align}\right.  $$
>
> which clearly goes to zero.